# Cannot close frame using button after opening a new one in swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, standards, swing-app-framework

```
package bt;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class login extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener, javax.swing.RootPaneContainer  {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextField TUserID=new JTextField(20);
private JPasswordField TPassword=new JPasswordField(20);
protected int role;
public JButton bLogin = new JButton("continue");
private JButton bCancel = new JButton("cancel");


public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new login().createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}



public void createAndShowGUI() {
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("");
    JLabel l = new JLabel();   
    JLabel l2 = new JLabel("(2011)");
    l2.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.BOLD, 10));
    l.setIcon(icon);
    JLabel LUserID=new JLabel("Your User ID: ");
    JLabel LPassword=new JLabel("Your Password: ");
    TUserID.addActionListener(this);
    TPassword.addActionListener(this);
    TUserID.setText("correct");
    TPassword.setEchoChar('*');
    TPassword.setText("correct");
    bLogin.setOpaque(true);
    bLogin.addActionListener(this);
    bCancel.setOpaque(true);
    bCancel.addActionListener(this);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("continue");

    f.setUndecorated(true);
    f.setSize(460,300);

    AWTUtilitiesWrapper.setWindowOpaque(f, false);
        AWTUtilitiesWrapper.setWindowOpacity(f, ((float) 80) / 100.0f);
    Container pane = f.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
    pane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Box box0 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box0.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box0.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    box0.add(l);
    box0.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
    pane.add(box0);

    Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 20, 100));
    box.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
    box.add(LUserID);
    box.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(32, 0)));
    box.add(TUserID);
    LUserID.setMaximumSize( LUserID.getPreferredSize() );
    TUserID.setMaximumSize( TUserID.getPreferredSize() );
    pane.add(box);

    Box box2 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box2.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
    box2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 20, 100));
    box2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(100, 0)));
    box2.add(LPassword,LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    box2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(15, 0)));
    box2.add(TPassword,LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    LPassword.setMaximumSize( LPassword.getPreferredSize() );
    TPassword.setMaximumSize( TPassword.getPreferredSize() );
    pane.add(box2);

    Box box3 = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box3.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 0, 100));
    box3.add(bLogin);
    box3.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
    box3.add(bCancel);
    pane.add(box3);

    f.setLocation(450,300);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setBackground(Color.BLACK); 
    f.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

    String TBUsername = TUserID.getText();
    Object src = evt.getSource();
    char[] CHPassword1 = TPassword.getPassword();
    String TBPassword = String.valueOf(CHPassword1);

    login mLogin = this;

    if (src==bLogin) {

        if (authenticate(TBUsername,TBPassword)) {
            System.out.println(this);
            exitApp(this);
        } else {
            exitApp(this);
        }

    } else if (src==bCancel) {
        exitApp(mLogin);
    }
}

public void exitApp(JFrame mlogin) {
    mlogin.setVisible(false);
}

private boolean authenticate(String uname, String pword) {
    if ((uname.matches("correct")) && (pword.matches("correct"))) {
        new MyJFrame().createAndShowGUI();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

and MyJFrame.java

```
package bt;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class MyJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame implements ActionListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 2871032446905829035L;
private JButton bExit = new JButton("Exit (For test purposes)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MyJFrame().createAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
}


public void createAndShowGUI() {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setBackground(Color.black);
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("(2011)");      //up to here
    l.setIcon(icon);
    p.add(l);
    p.add(bExit);
    bExit.setOpaque(true);
    bExit.addActionListener(this);

    JFrame f = new JFrame("frame");

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setUndecorated(true);
    p.setOpaque(true);
    f.getContentPane().add(p);
    f.pack();
    f.setSize(1000,600);
    Container pane=f.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1) );
    //p.setPreferredSize(200,200);

    AWTUtilitiesWrapper.setWindowOpaque(f, false);
        AWTUtilitiesWrapper.setWindowOpacity(f, ((float) 90) / 100.0f);

    f.setLocation(300,300);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    Object src = evt.getSource();
    if (src==bExit) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

I cannot get the exitApp() method to work, although it worked before I expanded on my code, I've been trying for hours to get it to work but no avail! The login button suceeds in opening the new frame but will not close the preious(login) frame. It did earlier till I added the validation method etc ....

Comment: See my advice on [Working with 2 or more frames](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889922/working-with-2-or-more-frames/7890456#7890456), which basically boils down to "don't - use alternatives".

Comment: @Pam  Am I correct at understanding that you want to display a login dialog, then, if that works, display a proper screen which will then exit whn the exitApp() method is invoked?  If so, you have to slightly redesign your solution. What is interesting though is that it works on my machine? I can log in and when I click on the Exit button, the windows close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create only one `JFrame` as parent and for another [Top-level Containers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) create only once `JDialog` (put there `JPanel` as base), and re-use that for another Action, then you only to remove all JComponents from Base JPanel and add there another JPanel

don't forget for as last lines after switch betweens `JPanels` inside `Base JPanel`

```
revalidate();
repaint();
```

you can pretty to forgot about that by implements [CardLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)